# How to add shortcut for stop project on the right top of the Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

In the default setting:

[image]

The red block doesn't exist. How do I add it to 
the right top place, just like the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Looks ok. Did you press `OK` and restart IntelliJ? How does it look now? please add a picture and a version of IntelliJ.

Comment: The following is the default that works fine: https://i.imgur.com/ycA8UYy.png.

Comment: @mgershen please check my update. Thanks in advance!

Comment: My setup looks just like your last picture and I have the stop icon.
I wanted you to add a picture of how your tool bar looks like (a picture similar to the first one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctrl + alt + s` to open `Settings`.

choose `Run with Coverage`--click `Add After`.

[image]

choose `Main menu`--`Run`--`Stop`--click 'OK'.

[image]

Before, I misunderstood what "Add After" mean.

The point here is, firstly, you choose the icon you want to add sth after it. Then, in the "Choose Actions To Add", you choose which icon you want to add.